# Razor syntax in core class project

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, view

I've added a core class project to my solution with a controller and view. The solution runs and loads the controller and view fine.

The problem is I don't have the razor syntax in the view. I'd like to use the @Model and the helpers etc. I've seen information online but none relating to .Net Core class projects.

Help would be good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the class project to a mini Web project. [Razor support in non-web projects](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1854) is not a popular request at this moment.

Edit a `csproj` file to:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.2" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Add empty `Program` class with `Main` method cause compiler will ask for this.

Comment: I'm surprised. But this solution works. Much appreciated.